# O(nlogn) algo to minimize abs(x+y)

Tags: algorithm, modulus

I was asked a question in an interview I appeared in recently. I was not able to solve this problem. Interested people in algorithm design may like this problem.

Given an array of real numbers S, find a pair of numbers x&y in S that minimizes |x+y|. The algo for the same should be designed to run in O(nlogn).

I could not find a solution to this. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please to the solution of this problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the numbers. For each element x do a binary search for -x. You get the closest number y to minimize |x+y|.

Note: You can also optimize the second part. Start with indices for first and last element: i=0, j=n-1. At every iteration calculate the sum, update the minimum sum, and increment i if sum<0 or decrement j (when sum>=0).

Comment: That would be order of NlogN for sorting plus logN for searching right?

Comment: .. logN for each of the N searches you might do (you can also do only N/2 searches). You can optimize the second part further and make it only O(n), but overall it is still O(nlogn).

Comment: @ElKamina O(n) by stepping through from both sides at the same time? It's probably worth a mention in the answer. Same asymptotic complexity, but optimizing the constant factor can make a big difference.

Comment: @Dukeling Have added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The question by the interviewer - or your restatment - seems to be lacking in two ways.

1) Real numbers are very, very hard to represent in a computer. They can be represented in symbolic format, or a subset as floating point, and subsets of real numbers (like the integers)

2) Mod takes two arguments, their statement is to minimize mod(x+y) instead of mod(x,y).

Could this have been an interview problem designed to challenge that the statement of the problem is wrong?

Wikipedia defines "mod" as "Given two positive numbers, a (the dividend) and n (the divisor), a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) is the remainder of the Euclidean division of a by n."
and "euclidian division" as
"In arithmetic, the Euclidean division is the conventional process of division of two integers producing a quotient and a remainder. "

Further source that "mod" on real numbers doesn't make sense: http://www.abstractmath.org/MM/MMNumberTheory.htm

If the problem is defined as an array of integers minimizing mod(x,y) in O(nlogn), that seems tractable. You sort the array and for every element apply --- essentially --- a twist on a binary search for every pair. Doing a binary search over mod-space is left to the reader, as one would say.

I have several interview questions I use in the same way, finding out whether a candidate has the guts to question the question. This question might have the elements of both, having to question the idea of reals and mod on reals, then solving a tractable problem (a fairly traditional search data structure problem).

When I give those questions, the first part can be kind of a "gotcha" question, and I'll let them puzzle over that issue for a few minutes, and then re-present the problem as a tractable problem, just to move the interview along.

Comment: I don't know what the other answer is talking about since the question itself looks not right. +1.

Comment: By mod I mean x+y and which are then made unsigned ie, square root of (x+y)^2

Comment: @SilentPro That's what just the `|c|` does. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value). [`mod` is something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: The function is abs, not mod. mod isn't even mentioned in the question, and as you say would make no sense in this context.